# Angular 6 unit testing detectChange throws error for component with @input

Tags: angular, unit-testing

I have a simple component that is passed a config object as `@input` and uses it to set some values in `ngOnInit`

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
    @input() config: ConfigObject;
    min: number;
    max: number;

    ngOnInit() {
        this.min = this.config.range.min;
        this.max = this.config.range.max;
    }
}
```

And I test it as follows:

```
describe('MyComponent', () => {
    beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({...})
        .compileComponents();
    }));
    beforeEach(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        component.config = <ConfigObject>mockConfig;
        fixture.detectChanges();
    })
})
```

`detectChanges` here will throw an error `[object ErrorEvent] thrown`. 
If I call `ngOnInit` explicitly, I will receive `TypeError: Cannot read property 'min' of undefined`.
From [Angular's testing guide](https://angular.io/guide/testing#component-with-inputs-and-outputs) it seems like it should be possibly to set input explicitly on tested component, and then call `detectChanges` so I'm not sure why this isn't working.

In case you were wondering - the `mockConfig` object is a copy of the object passed to the component when code is run, and the component does not error in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give some mock value please check it now, it should work

```
  beforeEach(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        component.config = range: {min:0, max:100};
        fixture.detectChanges();
    })
})
```

Comment: this is what I'm doing with `mockConfig` it has `min` and `max` values and some other things I didn't specify here.

Comment: can you show exact code? I had same cases which was solved by the above code.